# Is there any method in python to display a message for particular time

Tags: python, string, console

Suppose if I want to display the message "Help me out!" for 15 minutes and after 15 minutes only the message "Help me out!" will no appear on interpreter console then which method is helpful in python?

```
print("Welcome")
string_variable="Help me out!"

print(string_variable)
```

Comment: Print it, make a time.sleep(15*60) and erase console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading
import time
import os

def clearAfter15():
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
    clear()

string_variable="Help me out!"
t = threading.Timer(15*60, clearAfter15)
t.start()
print(string_variable)
```

That should hopefully do the trick, I cant help much more than that without more detail

Comment: Tank u it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Do clear the interpreter terminal, import the `os` library and then do `os.system('cls')` (As described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)). Note that this will clear the entire terminal window.

In order to do it after 15 minutes, use `time.sleep(<amount of seconds>)`, so in your case `time.sleep(900)`.

Comment: this will add only delay to the message

Comment: If you first print the message, then sleep for 15 minutes and then clear the terminal, it will correctly do what was asked for, won't it?