# clear command line in python and microsoft visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I happen to be making an application that uses CLI.The problem I have is that I want to clean the screen to make it look better, but I don't know how to do it.  I tried to use `CLS` and `import os` it but I get a zero and it doesn't do the job, any idea about how to do this?.

for example:

```
import os
print ("hello world")
os.system('cls')
```

output:

```
hello world
♀Press any key to continue . .
```

i try:

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
print ("hello world")
clear()
```

still gives the same result in visual studio, now, if I try by CLI it works. I really don't understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Comment: does not work =(, for some reason in vs does not work and still gives the same result

Comment: By VS do you mean VS code?

Comment: not, microsoft visual studio 2019

Comment: Your question seems to be specifically about Visual Studio 2019 for Python, you may want to add an appropriate tag, since most people won't be using that editor and the answer for Python in general has already been provided.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I already made the change

Answer (score 5):

I imagine you have moved beyond this issue now but I've just run into this issue myself using Python in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 and found your question. Looks like its an open known bug with the "debug window" (python interpreter) in Visual Studio: https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/246.

If you uncheck Tee program output to Debug Output Window in the Python Debugging Options (see image)

[image]

then your posted code:

```
import os
print ("hello world")
os.system('cls')
```

will clear the screen for you in the VS interpreter window.