# Simple question but I cant find anyway online to delete an original output in the way for a new one

Tags: python

```
print ('hello, welcome to our bar')
age = int(input("What is your age"))

if age < 21:
    print ('*kicks your ass out of bar*')
else:
    print("come on in")
```

I am able to run the code and have it ask for a number, once you enter the number under the number the desired output comes out. What is want is for instead of the output to look like

```
hello, welcome to our bar
What is your age25
come on in
```

I want it to just look like

```
come on in
```

very new so sorry if this is super simple I have been searching for someone who has previously asked this but none of the code I'm finding works

Comment: Are you looking for `sys.stdout.flush()`? (Python 3: `print(text, flush=True)`)

Comment: try `clear = lambda : os.system('cls')` after age input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Comment: i think he/she/they/it don't want the input to be visible and just want the output to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

You can just clear the screen using the `os` module.

```
import os 

os.system('clear')
```

Use this code before printing "come on in" and import os in the beginning of your code like:

```
import os

print ('hello, welcome to our bar')
age = int(input("What is your age"))

if age < 21:
    print ('*kicks your ass out of bar*')
else:
    os.system('clear')
    print("come on in")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to just use `os` python module.

Though there're two ways in which you can do it i.e., using function or method and directly using `os` module.

- Using **function or method**

```js
import os

print ('hello, welcome to our bar \n')
age = int(input("What is your age \n"))

def ClearScreen():
   # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix')
   if os.name == 'posix':
      _ = os.system('clear')
   else:
      # for windows platfrom
      _ = os.system('cls')

if age < 21:
    ClearScreen()
    print ('*kicks your ass out of bar* \n')
     
else:
    ClearScreen()
    print("come on in \n")
```

- Using **os** module directly.

```js
import os

print ('hello, welcome to our bar \n')
age = int(input("What is your age \n"))

if age < 21:
    if os.name == 'posix':
      _ = os.system('clear')
    else:
      # for windows platfrom
      _ = os.system('cls')
    print ('*kicks your ass out of bar* \n')
     
else:
    if os.name == 'posix':
      _ = os.system('clear')
    else:
      # for windows platfrom
      _ = os.system('cls')
    print("come on in \n")
```