# Clear python console command histories

Tags: python, cls

'Cls' or 'clear' command doesn't work in my windows VSC console.
When I using mouse to scroll the terminal in VSC, the lines still have a lot.
Any advice for me?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Comment: Actually not...  Because 'cls' is fake. It looks like cleaned my console, but actually not, when i scroll the console, I discovered, those commands still there. There is a way can really clean it. Just kill the terminal and reopen it. But I wanna ask other possibility.