# How to detect if Python is running in Git Bash terminal, or Windows cmd?

Tags: python, cmd, git-bash

I'd like to give my Python scripts the ability to detect whether it was executed in a Git Bash terminal, or the Windows cmd command line interface. For example, I'm trying to write a function to clear the terminal (regardless of which terminal it is), e.g. echoes the `clear` command if in Git Bash, or `cls` if in cmd.

I've tried using sys.platform to detect this, but it returns `win32` regardless of which type of terminal it was ran in.

Comment: Try using ``os`` and ``psutil`` modules. For example, ```import os, psutil

# Get the parent process name.
pprocName = psutil.Process(os.getppid()).name()```

Comment: Also, please check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clear-screen-python/

Comment: Thanks, your example works for my particular use case.

Comment: Cool, I am glad to help. Do you want me to add it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using `os` and `psutil` modules.

For example,

```
import os, psutil  # Get the parent process name. 
pprocName = psutil.Process(os.getppid()).name()
```

Then you can have your logic depending on the shell.

Additionally, you may want to check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clear-screen-python/

Comment: This works. Tested with Command Prompt, Powershell, and Git Bash in a Windows x64 environment. Output will return cmd.exe, powershell.exe, or winpty-agent.exe respectively. This output, combined with the output from the sys.platform module in a conditional statement, will enable a user to issue terminal commands that are effectively shell agnostic, as well as os agnostic if desired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you're asking for is possible, but there are several answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console) that show all the detections you *can* do to use the correct type of clear. Usually, it's just best to either make your own window or not clear the screen, sadly.