# Is there a way in python to clear the output screen

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working on a tictactoe game and the output gets really messy and untidy after some inputs by the user, so is there any library or something I can use to clear the output screen after some time. The only method I know of works only for jupyter notebook. I'm using pycharm.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

os.system("cls")
```

cls would be clear on mac or linux
This should clear console

Comment: So if you are publishing you could do a if and find the the platform then run the respective command

Comment: Ok thanks, let me try that

Comment: [for reference](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-clear-console/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the OS library and run clear command

```
import os

os.system("clear")
```