# What is it called when a program takes control over a console, and how can one do that in python?

Tags: python, console, output

I am planning to make a python program which displays some sequential info in the console without adding newlines, i.e. similarly to what man does - the console is taken over by the program and all the input goes to the program, and the program is able to update text in place rather than having to print on a newline every time. I don't know what is the proper term for this, which makes for a "problem of unknown terminology" (which I'm sure has a proper name as well, but ironically I do not know it either), and thus makes it near impossible for me to search for the answer myself.

Comment: There is no real "taking over" taking place. All of things you mentioned can be achieved with combination of `input()`, `print()` and ANSI escape codes, more on which you can read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50560686/9296093)

Comment: Well, how exactly does man do that then? Is it also simply refreshing the output every time a new input comes in?