# os.system('cls') Doesn't clear screen when using ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary

Tags: python, ctypes, os.system

I am facing issue when I import a Python file that uses `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` function. When I try that, `os.system('cls')` doesn't clear the screen as it should. When I remove the line with `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary`, `os.system('cls')` works properly. The `.DLL` file contains a GoLang TLS solution. Code snippets below.

Here's an example file where `os.system('cls')` doesn't clear the screen.

```
import os
import tls

session = tls.create_client()

print('Session created.')

os.system('cls')

print('Screen cleared.')
```

`__init__.py` in `tls` dir:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    file_dir = f'{sys._MEIPASS}/tls/titanium_tls'
else:
    file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

tls = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(f'{file_dir}/titanum_test.{platform.system().lower()}' if str(platform.system()) != 'Windows' else f'{file_dir}/titanum_test.dll')

tls.Request.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
tls.Request.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
```

Output of example script:

```
Session created.
Screen cleared.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Output when `tls = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(f'{file_dir}/titanum_test.{platform.system().lower()}' if str(platform.system()) != 'Windows' else f'{file_dir}/titanum_test.dll')` line is removed:

```
Session created.
 Screen cleared.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The space is the place where `os.system('cls')` is clearing the screen and it works properly when the line that I mentioned above is removed.

Of course i cannot use my `__init__.py` file when this line is removed.

Sorry if there are any issues inside my questions.

Output returned by
`print(os.system('cls'))`
Is: `1`

Comment: Can you check the result of `os.system()`? The number should be the Windows error code if there was a problem.

Comment: result returned by print(os.system('cls')) is "1"

Comment: That very generically means "error". Do the other solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console work any better?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. The soulution is:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('cls', shell=True)
```