# Clearing Console in Python

Tags: python, console

I've been having trouble clearing the console on python. I've tried to do Console.Clear() and clear() but for some reason they haven't been working.

Answer (score 6):

I think this will help you:
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

There are multiple ways depends on your operating system

The fastest option would be:

```
print("\033c", end='')
```

Good luck :)

Comment: I'm using a website called replit, and I found out how to clear the console. Thank you anyway!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works, thank you!

Comment: @user18896432 have you tried glitch

Answer (score 1):

Are you using windows? Perhaps try:

```
import os
os.system(‘cls’)
```

to clear the console instead.

Comment: No, im using a chromebook.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS and Linux:

```
import os
os.system("clear")
```

for Windows:

```
import os
os.system("cls")
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, I use the following code snippet:

```py
import os
def clear(): os.system('cls')
```

Then, you type in `clear()`. It **does not produce an extra blank line** at the very top. This is in contrast to the solution provided by Ryan Duffield which uses lambda ([How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)). The reason for not having an extra blank line and zero when using a regular function is that the **regular function** *returns* **None**.