# Is there any inbuilt functions in python to delete console outputs whilst the code is running?

Tags: python, function

Does python have in-built functionality to delete console outputs whilst it runs or is there a library to do so

I have tried to find functions in python that might be able to clear the console outputs (while it runs to reduce the amount of words in the console) however my Searches came up fruitless

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Answer (score 0):

you can use clear module.

To install the package: pip install clear

import clear

clear.clear()