# Why is my console not being cleared in python?

Tags: python-3.x, console, ascii

Im trying to do an ASCII character animation in python but console doesn't clear. All various variants of clearing console method print 2-3 symbols but will not clear the console. I'm Using Visual studio 2022 on windows.

Following is the dummy code that I tried with:

```
import os 
print("@@@@@")
os.system("cls")
```

output:
[and this is what its continuously doing:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pECcx.png)

Comment: Rather than that, try `print("\033[H\033[J", end="")` per : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console

Comment: it works for me (`vscode` , `windows11`).... And it works in both the integrated terminal and the external terminal.

Comment: if you leave visual studio and run the code in a stand alone terminal, what happens ?  (i think it is a visual studio setting / error).