# How do I delete printed text? (Python 3.10.5)

Tags: python-3.x

For a long time I've been looking for a post that answers how to delete, or overwrite printed text. None of the stuff I tried worked.

I tried using \r, \b, `os.system('cls')`, `sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')` and `sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')`. None of these worked for me. Idk why.

```
string = 'This is a \rstring'
print(string)
```

what I expected:
strings a

what happened:
this is a string

---

```
string = 'This is a string'
print(string + 6 * "\b")
```

what I expected:
This is a

what happened:
This is a string
(There was some characters after the "This is a string" They didn't show up)

I think you can see where this is going. If anyone has an answer that works for windows, python 3.10.5 (Every other version that people answered in didn't work for me), thank you in advance if you answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Comment: Where/how do you execute this code?

Comment: I want to make something that updates the text a lot, so it looks better than just making a new line everytime something changes.

Comment: all the answers in the "how to clear the interpreter console" didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
import time

print("hello world!")
time.sleep(1)
print("\033[1F\033[0K\033[1F")
print("goodbye")
```

You will need Windows 10 version 1511 or later for this to work.

For older Windows version, install and `import` [`colorama`](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't work for me. All I got was
"hello world!
[1F[0K[1F
goodbye" (with arrows pointing left after every "[")

Comment: I have windows 10 version 19045. It still doesn't seem to work though.