# Blackjack not clearing console once game is complete and new one is started

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with getting my blackjack game to clear the console once the game is completed and a new game is started. Instead, the game adds the new cards to the previous game making an instant loss? Below is my code.

```py
import random
from replit import clear
from art import logo

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

def deal_card():
    return random.choice(cards)

player_cards = [] 
computer_cards = []

def deal_round():
    for i in range(2):
        player_cards.append(deal_card())   
        computer_cards.append(deal_card())

def calculate_score(n1):
    if sum(n1) == 21 and len(n1) == 2:
        return 0
    if 11 in n1 and len(n1) > 2:
        n1.remove(11)
        n1.append(1)
    return sum(n1)

def compare(player_sum, computer_sum):
    if player_sum > 21 and computer_sum > 21:
        return "You went over. You lose."
    elif player_sum == computer_sum:
        return "Draw"
    elif computer_sum == 0:
        return "Computer Blackjack!. You lose!"
    elif player_sum == 0:
        return "Blackjack. You won the game!"
    elif player_sum > 21:
        return "You lose!"
    elif computer_sum > 21:
        return "Computer went over. You win!"
    elif player_sum > computer_sum:
        return "You win!"
    else:
        return "You lose!"
        
def blackjack():
    
    print(logo)
    end_of_game = False
    deal_round()
    
    def computer_card():
        return computer_cards[0]
    
    while not end_of_game:
    
        player_sum = calculate_score(player_cards)
        computer_sum = calculate_score(computer_cards)      
            
        
        print(f"Your cards are: {player_cards}, current score: {player_sum}")   
        print(f"Computer's first card: {computer_card()}")

        if player_sum == 0 or computer_sum == 0 or player_sum >21:
            end_of_game = True
        else:   
            if input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ") == 'y':
                player_cards.append(deal_card())
            else:
                end_of_game = True
        
    while computer_sum <= 16:
        computer_cards.append(deal_card())
        computer_sum = calculate_score(computer_cards)
    print(f"Your final hand: {player_cards}, final score: {player_sum}")
    print(f"Computer's final hand: {computer_cards}, final score: {computer_sum}")
    print(compare(player_sum, computer_sum))
        
while input("Do you want to play a game of Blackjack? Type 'y' or 'n': ") == "y":
    clear()
    blackjack()
```

I've tried to move the clear function into the blackjack function but, resulted in the same outcome. I also attempted to use the import os in place of the clear function but no success.

Comment: Is the issue with `clear()` and whatever that does (potentially clearing the screen?) or is the issue with resetting the game status after each round?

Comment: Why is `while computer_sum <= 16` where it is?

Comment: @JonSG is correct.  From the discussions on ask.replit.com, the `replit.clear` function is a console (i.e. screen) clearing function.  It does nothing to reinitialize your variables.

Comment: Move the initialization of `player_cards` and `computer_cards` inside your final while loop,

Comment: JonSG - Yes, the issue is with clear() and the getting it to reset the game after each round. I'm currently using replit to build this.

Comment: Thank you everyone! That worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replit.clear()` will apparently clear the screen, but that does not reset the game state.

Check out [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console) for alternatives to clearing the screen. I like `print("\033c")`.

What you likely really want to do is reset the game state between rounds. So each round you want to reset:

```
    player_cards = [] 
    computer_cards = []
```

So, if your final while loops was:

```py
while input("Do you want to play a game of Blackjack? Type 'y' or 'n': ") == "y":
    #clear()
    print("\033c")

    player_cards = [] 
    computer_cards = []
    blackjack()
```

You will likely get past your current issue.