How to clear multiple previous lines in the console in Python 3?
I'm trying to create a simple console output Tetris game in python, similar to the very original version, but I am having trouble clearing the previous lines/playfield to place the new one on top.
from time import sleep

# blocks is a 20x10 array filled with 0s and 1s

running = True

while running:
    for y in range(20):
        for x in range(10):
            if blocks[y][x] == 1:
                print('[#]', end='')
            else:
                print(' . ', end='')
        print("\n", end="")
    sleep(1)

    #trying to clear the lines
    for i in range(20):
        print(f"\033[F", "\r", end="")

How can I most effectively remove the previous 20 lines printed?
Being able to remove a select amount of lines (via a for loop for example) would be preferable, but clearing the whole screen could work if that seems to be the only solution.
For context, I am running this script on PyCharm on Mac.

Try os.system('cls'), if that doesn't work, then use os.system('clear').

calling an external process each game frame does not sound really smart.

see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50560686/218663

Does this answer your question? How can I clear the interpreter console?

While OP might find an answer to their question in one of the answers of the mentioned "duplicate" question, both questions are quite different, hence not duplicate.

Printing the sequence \033[F twenty times as you are doing should work - although there are other ways.
If the cursor is not moving up 20 lines, try running your script from the terminal (the real, system, terminal) instead of from within Pycharm: it may be that is emulated terminal simply do not support cursor positioning sequences.
Although, this ANSI sequence for "cursor up" can move all lines needed in a single run, and there is no need to repeat it 20 times - Just add the number of repetitions between the [ and F characters:
print("\x1b[20F")

(Note that I prefer using the hex code \x1b instead of octal \033 for the ESC character - both yield the same code, but few things are easier to think in octal than in Hex. But that can be a matter of taste).
Don't fall for the suggestions of running an external "clear" or "cls" process just for erasing the screen: that is the computational equivalent of calling a locksmith to enter and exit you house when the door lock is perfectly functional and you have the keys.
There are other ANSI sequences that might interest you - check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code - including sequences to erase the whole screen, or position the cursor at fixed coordinates.

You can use os.system("clear") on Mac or Linux and os.system("cls") for Windows, from the os module. This will clear the printed text so you can rerender it next update of the game
import os
from time import sleep
while running:
    for y in range(20):
        for x in range(10):
            if blocks[y][x] == 1:
                print('[#]', end='')
            else:
                print(' . ', end='')
        print("\n", end="")
    sleep(1)


    os.system("clear")


Should be mentioned this runs the external command clear which will clear the screen when it exists. This depends on the OS and shell used. Windows cmd users would use os.system("cls") instead.

I didn't mention it because he specified that he was on Mac.  I'll edit the answer to fix  that

Yes, you are correct and I saw that before writing my comment. My thought was that future readers may find your answer more helpful if it addresses their OS.
